# Merge cells in HTML table in SQL

Tags: html, sql, sql-server, xml

I am using this query to create an HTML table and send it by email.
Is there any way to merge the cells for the Group ID and Total Transaction Sum columns only if they have the same value to improve readability?
Below is the result I want to get

```
CREATE TABLE #list (GroupID int,AccountID int,Country varchar (20),AccountTransactionSum int)

Insert into #list
values 
(1,18754,'United Kingdom',110),
(1,24865,'Germany',265),
(1,82456,'Poland',1445),
(1,98668,'United Kingdom',60),
(1,37843,'France',1490),
(2,97348,'United Kingdom',770)

DECLARE @xmlBody      XML   
SET @xmlBody = (SELECT (SELECT  GroupID,                        AccountID,                      Country,            AccountTransactionSum,          TotalTransactionSum = sum(AccountTransactionSum) over (partition by GroupID)
                        FROM #list
                        ORDER BY GroupID 
                        FOR XML PATH('row'), TYPE, ROOT('root')).query('<html><head><meta charset="utf-8"/><style>
                                                                            table <![CDATA[ {border-collapse: collapse; } ]]>
                                                                            th <![CDATA[ {background-color: #4CAF50; color: white;} ]]>
                                                                            th, td <![CDATA[ { text-align: center; padding: 8px;} ]]>
                                                                            tr:nth-child(even) <![CDATA[ {background-color: #f2f2f2;} ]]>
                                                                            </style></head>
                                                                            <body><table border="1" cellpadding="10" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
                                                                            <thead><tr>
                                                                            <th>No.</th>
                                                                            <th> Group ID </th><th> Account ID </th><th> Country </th><th> Account Transaction Sum </th><th> Total Transaction Sum </th>
                                                                            </tr></thead>
                                                                            <tbody>
                                                                            {for $row in /root/row
                                                                            let $pos := count(root/row[. << $row]) + 1
                                                                            return <tr align="center" valign="center">
                                                                            <td>{$pos}</td>
                                                                            <td>{data($row/GroupID)}</td><td>{data($row/AccountID)}</td><td>{data($row/Country)}</td><td>{data($row/AccountTransactionSum)}</td><td>{data($row/TotalTransactionSum)}</td>
                                                                            </tr>}
                                                                            </tbody></table></body></html>'));

    
select @xmlBody
```

result I have

[image]

result I would like to have

[image: result I would like to have]

link to the HTML editor
https://codebeautify.org/real-time-html-editor/y237bf87d

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a great question, because I didn't know `xquery` could do this magic!
This is what I came up with:

```sql
DROP TABLE #list
go
SELECT  *
INTO    #list
FROM    (
VALUES 
(1,18754,'United Kingdom',110),
(1,24865,'Germany',265),
(1,82456,'Poland',1445),
(1,98668,'United Kingdom',60),
(1,37843,'France',1490),
(2,97348,'United Kingdom',770)
) t (groupid,accountid, country, AccountTransactionSum)

DECLARE @xmlBody      XML   
SET @xmlBody = (SELECT  (SELECT GroupID, 
                                AccountID, 
                                Country, 
                                AccountTransactionSum,
                                TotalTransactionSum = sum(AccountTransactionSum) OVER (partition BY GroupID),
                                COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY GroupID) AS rowspan,
                                CASE WHEN lag(GroupID) OVER(ORDER BY groupid,accountid) = GroupID THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS skipTd
                        FROM    #list ll
                        ORDER BY GroupID, accountid
                        FOR XML PATH('row'), TYPE, ROOT('root')).query('<html><head><meta charset="utf-8"/><style>
                                                                            table <![CDATA[ {border-collapse: collapse; } ]]>
                                                                            th <![CDATA[ {background-color: #4CAF50; color: white;} ]]>
                                                                            th, td <![CDATA[ { text-align: center; padding: 8px;} ]]>
                                                                            tr:nth-child(even) <![CDATA[ {background-color: #f2f2f2;} ]]>
                                                                            </style></head>
                                                                            <body><table border="1" cellpadding="10" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
                                                                            <thead><tr>
                                                                            <th>No.</th>
                                                                            <th> Group ID </th><th> Account ID </th><th> Country </th><th> Account Transaction Sum </th><th> Total Transaction Sum </th>
                                                                            </tr></thead>
                                                                            <tbody>
                                                                            {for $row in /root/row
                                                                            let $pos := count(root/row[. << $row]) + 1

                                                                            return 
                                                                            if ($row/skipTd > 0) then
                                                                            <tr align="center" valign="center">
                                                                            <td>{$pos}</td>
                                                                            <td>{data($row/AccountID)}</td>
                                                                            <td>{data($row/Country)}</td>
                                                                            <td>{data($row/AccountTransactionSum)}</td>
                                                                            </tr>
                                                                            else
                                                                            if ($row/rowspan > 1) then
                                                                            
                                                                            <tr align="center" valign="center">
                                                                            <td>{$pos}</td>
                                                                            <td rowspan ="{data($row/rowspan)}">{data($row/GroupID)}</td>
                                                                            <td>{data($row/AccountID)}</td>
                                                                            <td>{data($row/Country)}</td>
                                                                            <td>{data($row/AccountTransactionSum)}</td>
                                                                            <td rowspan ="{data($row/rowspan)}">{data($row/TotalTransactionSum)}</td>
                                                                            </tr>
                                                                            else
                                                                            <tr align="center" valign="center">
                                                                            <td>{$pos}</td>
                                                                            <td>{data($row/GroupID)}</td>
                                                                            <td>{data($row/AccountID)}</td>
                                                                            <td>{data($row/Country)}</td>
                                                                            <td>{data($row/AccountTransactionSum)}</td>
                                                                            <td>{data($row/TotalTransactionSum)}</td>
                                                                            </tr>
                                                                            }
                                                                            </tbody></table></body></html>'));

    
SELECT  @xmlBody
```

Basically I create two columns, rowspan and skipTd. First controls if rowspan should be applicable, and second says if the current `<td>` should be skipped because it's part of same group.

Then I added a nested if to the xquery so it returns either rowspanned, "skipped" or normal HTML depending on these two flags. Maybe there's a nicer way to do it, I'm no expert.

Comment: Upvoted, i am missing a couple of newer features too

Answer (score 1):

For Siggemannen's very good answer i just want to add an alternative way to deal with those td's inside xquery,

```
SELECT  GroupID, 
        AccountID, 
        Country, 
        AccountTransactionSum,
        TotalTransactionSum = sum(AccountTransactionSum) over (partition by GroupID),
        rowspan = COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY GroupID),
        display = CASE WHEN lag(GroupID) OVER(ORDER BY GroupID,AccountID) = GroupID THEN 'display:none' ELSE '' END
FROM #list
```

after rowspan and display defined you can use them in your xquery for loop

```
for $row in /root/row
let $pos := count(root/row[. << $row]) + 1
return 
<tr align="center" valign="center" id="{data($row/TotalCount)}">
 <td>{$pos}</td>
 <td style="{data($row/display )}" rowspan="{data($row/rowspan)}">{data($row/GroupID)}</td>
 <td>{data($row/AccountID)}</td>
 <td>{data($row/Country)}</td>
 <td>{data($row/AccountTransactionSum)}</td>
 <td style="{data($row/display )}" rowspan="{data($row/rowspan)}">{data($row/TotalTransactionSum)}</td>
</tr>
```