# Dbmail SQL Server group rows in html

Tags: sql-server, database-mail

I can't find how to do this - help me please.

I'm using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio

```
EXEC spQueryToHtmlTable 
            @html = @html OUTPUT,
            @query = N'select col1 , col2, col3 from table', 
            @orderBy = N'ORDER BY 1';
```

In my E-mail I will see (html table)

```
        col1 |    col2    | col3
row1   apple | warehouse1 | 4
row2   apple | warehouse2 | 4
row3   apple | warehouse3 | 4
```

How to group by col 1 and col3? (duplicate rows)

I need to get this in the email (html table):

```
        col1 |    col2    | col3
row1         | warehouse1 | 
row2   apple | warehouse2 | 4
row3         | warehouse3 |
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Merge cells in HTML table in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75560761/merge-cells-in-html-table-in-sql)

Answer (score 0):

You can use window functions and a bit of integer arithmetic here:

```sql
SET @query = N'
select
  col1 = CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY col1, col3 ORDER BY col2)
                 = (COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY col1, col3) + 1) / 2
              THEN col1 END,
  col2,
  col3 = CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY col1, col3 ORDER BY col2)
                 = (COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY col1, col3) + 1) / 2
              THEN col3 END
from [table];
';
```

Comment: thanks, but this cannot, group htmls. group only data in table